# Questions on Graph Theory:

Tags: graph-theory

Prove:

1. Every collection of 6 people contains a group of 3 friends or a group of 3 strangers.
2. The shortest closed walk is a cycle.

(Don't have any idea how I will solve the first statement. For the second statement I just say that if there is a closed walk keep removing repeated edges. For example if $r----r$ was repeated in between the walk then keep removing it and you'll end up with a shorter closed walk - Till a point where it can't become any shorter. The end result is a cycle.)

Comment: For 1.  Start with your favourite person in the room.  That person either knows at least three people or doesn't know at least three people.  Consider those two (symmetrical) situations separately.

Comment: Thanks. It's pretty simple to solve the first statement now. Is my proof for the second statement correct.

Comment: For 2. You should probably be more specific about what you mean by removing the repeated edge.  It seems to me that you might have to remove some other additional edges as well.  Also, check your definitions, but, if I walk along an edge and then back along the same edge, why isn't that a closed walk?